# c# file upload to AWS

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-upload

Hello and apologies in advance for the noob question.  I'm also relatively new to c#.  In ASP.NET core, I can save files via the file upload control to AWS S3. However, this relies on me saving the files first to a location on my hard drive and then I can send in the path for the AWS code to pick it up from there. I'm sure it will be a simple answer but I can't find this after a few days' searching.  As anyone who uses my site can upload (and later download) pdfs and jpegs, how do I either (1) save the file to a temporary location on their machine or phone, or, preferably, (2) 'somehow' send in the path so the AWS code can pick it up? There are many posts stating how you can't get at the path for security reasons but as far as I can tell, the AWS code relies on it.

Here's the AWS code I'm using (from their documentation).  It works for me (overwrites the last file and there's no error handling yet, but one thing at once for me).  The bucketName and keyName are set up elsewhere.

It's how to send in the filePath without saving it anywhere that I can't get to work. The error just says that it can't find the file, understandably.

```
public void FileProcess(string filePath)
{

    client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);
    Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest request = new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest()
    {
        BucketName = bucketName,
        Key = keyName,
        FilePath = filePath
    };

    PutObjectResponse response2 = client.PutObject(request);

}
```

Comment: Post the actual error you get. That will help.

Comment: Saving to a location on disk shouldn't be necessary at all. Surely their client allows you to upload a byte array directly?

Comment: Hi, many, many thanks for the response on this.  After more hunting I found that it's Transfer Utility that I needed.          IAmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2);
        TransferUtility utility = new TransferUtility(client);
        TransferUtilityUploadRequest request = new ...

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to post all the code or close this item but the link that helped me is here - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fileupload-to-aws-s3-using-asp-net/